# VB Script for Opening PowerPoint file fails

Tags: vbscript

I am using VBScript to open a PowerPoint file (Office 2010 in Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit)

Below is the code snippet:

```
Set objPowerPoint = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

objPowerPoint.Visible = TRUE

Set openPPT = objPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Directory\Sample.pptx")

openPPT .SaveAs PathOfPDF("C:\Directory\ConvertedPDFs"), POWERPOINT_PDF, True
```

While running this script I get the below message in the line opening the presentation:

> "Unspecified error...Error Code 80004005..Source:(null)"

`PathofPDF` is a separate function used for saving it to PDF, but it is not even going to that and failing while opening the PPTX file.

The file does exist and I am able to open the file manually in PowerPoint. I am having access to the file and the directory, hence I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Also, I tried the VBScript on another system with Windows 7 64-bit & Office 2010 and it ran absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you create a new presentation (`Set ppt = objPowerPoint.Presentations.Add`) or does that fail as well?

Comment: It fails as well with the same error.

Comment: Then you seem to have a problem with the PowerPoint installation on that computer. Was the program installed with VBA support?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that. I have also writtem similar vb scripts for excel to PDF & Word to PDF conversion and it works properly. Is only for Powerpoint to PDF that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to open it? As long as `pptx` files are properly associated with PowerPoint, you should be able to just "shell" the file and it will open.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & "C:\Directory\Sample.pptx" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: I actually need to Open It and Save the Powerpoint file as PDF.

I am using this piece of code initially:

Set objPowerPoint = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

objPowerPoint.Visible = TRUE

Set openPPT = objPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Directory\Sample.pptx")

openPPT .SaveAs PathOfPDF("C:\Directory\ConvertedPDFs"), POWERPOINT_PDF, True

PathofPDF is a separate function used for saving it to PDF. But it is not even going to that and failing while opening the PPTX file